# Android events based on current screen

Tags: android, events, touch

I'm currently just starting my first android app

Like most apps I have a start screen that will go into the menu as soon as you touch the screen.

The question I have is what is the best way to go about registering touch actions in OnTouchEvent() based on which screen is currently showing.

Would it be better to put a switch or if/else statement based on what is showing or is there a better way?

EDIT FOR CLARITY:  For example say you start your app and it loads the title screen.  When you touch anywhere on the title screen it loads the first page which has a lot of menu buttons on it.

The OnTouchEvent() would have code the says "when touch anywhere display the first screen."

What I want is now that the menu screen is currently displayed on the screen instead of the title screen.  I no longer want to "when touch anywhere display the first screen."  Instead I would like to have the buttons perform different actions based on what their title is.  Therefore I would have to change what happens in the OnTouchEvent().

So what I'm asking is would it be better to have a bunch of if/else statements in my OnTouchEvent() or would there be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

Your main.xml layout. eg main.xml

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  // your other views ....

  </LinearLayout>
```

Your Activity

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{ 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   { 
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

   setContentView(R.layout.main); 

   findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setOnTouchListener(this);

   } 

@Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
   { 

      // do whatever you want
   } 
 }
```